# Getting around type erasure in Java/GWT

Tags: java, generics, gwt, type-erasure

In a GWT project, I have a method with this signature:

```
public <H> HandlerRegistration addHandler(Event.Type<H> type, H handler)
```

In that method, I want to include some logging messages; specifically, I want to know `<H>` so I can log what was passed. Java generic type erasure, being the way it works, compiles it out and it effectively becomes `Object`. And, being GWT, I can't use some of the fancier reflection techniques as they're not compatible with GWT. So, if I read `type.getClass().getName()`, there's no mention of what `<H>` is.

Is there some way around this?

Comment: But calling `handler.getClass()` will give you the actual `<H>` class ;).

Comment: But is polymorphism allowed for generics in Java? For example, am I allowed to pass an `Event.Type<Object> type` and a `String handler` because `String` extends `Object`?

Comment: You can't pass `String` here, because in GWT method looks like: `... <H extends EventHandler> HandlerRegistration addHandler(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I would call `getClass().getName()` on `handler` rather than on `type`. This should work no matter the handler implementation or Event Type. You will get back the Class object that represents the runtime class `<H>`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29

Comment: However, calling that on a handler that implements two different interfaces will tell you nothing useful - you don't know which event it was registered for.